# How to implement (fast) paint bucket tool for image editing program?

Tags: java, image, algorithm, bufferedimage

I am looking for a way to implement one of the tools for my image editing program, which is the paint bucket tool (similar to the one found in GIMP or Microsoft Paint).

### Expected result:

[image: before and after]

### How my program works:

My program contains one singleton object: `ImagePanelSingleton`. This singleton contains a `BufferedImage`, which is displayed to the user. The user is allowed to draw on the image with various tools, which causes the singleton to `#repaint()` itself.

So far, the only tool implemented in the program is the pencil tool (also found in GIMP and Microsoft Paint). All tools implement the `MouseAdapter` interface and are added to the singleton as listeners.

### What I thought of so far:

I am thinking of using a non-recursive flood-fill algorithm to perform the task. I want to make this tool work fast and efficiently, so I have considered using `#BufferedImage.getRaster()`. I don't know how to get started.

### Requirements:

The implementation must be able to work on images with/without an alpha channel, and it must be fast for large images (for example, 1500x1500 pixels).

The tool should only work if the user holds down the `Ctrl` key and left-clicks on one of the pixels in the image. There are no restrictions on the color used. It must work the same way as the paint bucket tool in GIMP or Microsoft Paint.

There is only one method that is required to be implemented, which is in the `BucketTool.java` class.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    public Main() {
        this.setTitle("Paint Bucket Demo");
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(ImagePanelSingleton.INSTANCE, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }
}
```

---

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class ImagePanelSingleton extends JPanel {
    public BufferedImage editableImage;
    public static final ImagePanelSingleton INSTANCE = new ImagePanelSingleton();

    private ImagePanelSingleton() {
        // initialize the BufferedImage and give it a white background
        editableImage = new BufferedImage(300, 300, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)editableImage.getGraphics();
        g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 300);

        // add some mouse motion controls to this JPanel - i.e. the mouse drawing and paint bucket tool
        MouseAdapter drawTool = new PencilTool();
        this.addMouseListener(drawTool);
        this.addMouseMotionListener(drawTool);

        MouseAdapter bucketTool = new BucketTool();
        this.addMouseListener(bucketTool);
        this.addMouseMotionListener(bucketTool);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        final int WIDTH = editableImage.getWidth();
        final int HEIGHT = editableImage.getHeight();

        return new Dimension(WIDTH + 100, HEIGHT + 100);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(editableImage, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class PencilTool extends MouseAdapter {
    private Point initial;
    private Point end;

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        initial = e.getPoint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        end = e.getPoint();

        // draw a line
        BufferedImage image = ImagePanelSingleton.INSTANCE.editableImage;
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)image.getGraphics();
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.drawLine(initial.x, initial.y, end.x, end.y);

        ImagePanelSingleton.INSTANCE.repaint();

        // re-assign the initial point
        initial = e.getPoint();
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class BucketTool extends MouseAdapter {

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // do nothing if the Ctrl key is not being held down
        if (!e.isControlDown())
            return;

        // How should I implement the rest of this method?




        ImagePanelSingleton.INSTANCE.repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.google.de/?gws_rd=ssl#safe=off&q=flood+fill+algorithm+java

Comment: I think you're headed in the right direction with the non-recursive, queue-based flood-fill algorithm, have you looked at the pseudo-code on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill)?

Comment: @JonnyHenly Yes I have. The algorithm is not what's causing the problem here, though. I need to also figure out a fast way of manipulating the pixels using Java's implementation of `BufferedImage`.

Comment: `BufferedImage` has a `#setRGB` method - have you checked that out?

Comment: @sina I'm aware of it, but I'm not sure if it'll be fast enough.

Comment: Well, we don't know your performance requirements, so I suppose it's best if you try to implement the algorithm with the known methods and if it's not performant enough ask again for improvements?

Comment: @zxgear if you solved your problem can u share the answer becouse I'm also compare with same issue, completed all shapes just cannot create paint bucket. There is no library or ready algorithm to use?